# How do I browse other guilds while I'm already in a guild?

Tags: lost-ark

I am already in a guild, but I would like to browse other guilds.

Do I have to create a new character that isn't in a guild yet/leave a guild with one of my characters or is there a less costly solution — e.g. a search hidden in one of the game's many windows?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only browse guilds from a character that is not part of one. So yes, to browse guilds you need to try to access the guild interface from a character that's not currently in a guild.